# CSS Grid/Tailwind dynamic insertion at "next row", while still being responsive

Tags: css, flexbox, grid, css-grid, tailwind-css

I have a grid like this using Tailwind:

```
<div class="grid auto-rows-max grid-cols-2 gap-6 sm:grid-cols-3 sm:gap-8 md:grid-cols-4 md:gap-10 lg:grid-cols-5">
  <div>product</div>
  <div>product</div>
  <div>product</div>
  <div>product</div>
  <div>product</div>
  <div>product</div>
  <div>product</div>
</div>
```

Notice that the CSS grid is 2 columns on mobile, 3 the size up, 4 on tablet, etc.

What I want is to create a "product detail" row thats injected underneath the currently clicked row. So if it's 2 columns, and you click the first item, the detail row would appear as the 3rd item with a `col-span-2` (because the detail row is an 'injected' entire row thats underneath whatever row is clicked)

Can I achieve this with CSS grid only, before having to resort to a lot of hacks with computing order in JavaScript based on screen size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it is by relying completely on `order` and responsive utilities. Of course, this method works for your example but will run out of steam pretty quickly since Tailwind's default order only goes to 12 and you will find yourself adding a ton of new order variants to your Tailwind config... also the algorithm to make this happen based on an element's position would get pretty gnarly after 20+ grid items.

What I did was leave spaces between the order for each of the main (product) items, for example, the first two items have `order-first` since they will always be first on all screen sizes but the rest are spaced out item 3 is `order-2`, item 4 `order-4` etc. Then the product detail just needs to fall in the slot after each row based on the screen size. This gets a little tricky, Product 1 and 2's detail for example would get the following classes (excluding the word order for simplicity) `1 sm:3 md:5 lg:7` whereas Product 3 would get `5 sm:3 md:5 lg:7` and Product 4 `5 sm:9 md:5 lg:7` and Product 5 would get `order-9 md:11 lg:7` which presents a strange pattern to try and automate but I'm sure someone has done a similar thing using modulus in JS and if you have a small amount it should be easy to do a case statement or keep an array reference and select the right class group based on the product's index. Final note on the details they should get `col-span-full` to prevent the need for calculating the `col-span-x` based on screen size as well.

Here's a Play example showing how all the details can fall in the right slots per screen size while directly following their related element with just the power of `order` utilities https://play.tailwindcss.com/tMHIF2Rpfy